# error in clone system call sentence in c++

Tags: c++, linux, clone

I am trying to to run c code in c++ which uses clone inside , I got an error which I couldn't solve it , anyone used clone in c++ before , and can help .

my code:

```
int variable, fd;
using namespace std ;
int do_something() {
variable = 42;cout << "sana" << endl ;
close(fd);
_exit(0);
}

int main() {
void **child_stack;
char tempch;

variable = 9;
fd = open("test.file", O_RDONLY);
child_stack = (void **) malloc(16384);
printf("The variable was %d\n", variable);

clone(do_something, child_stack,CLONE_VM|CLONE_FILES, NULL);
sleep(1);

printf("The variable is now %d\n", variable);
if (read(fd, &tempch, 1) < 1) {
  perror("File Read Error");
  exit(1);
}
printf("We could read from the file\n");
return 0;
}
```

and i got the errors:

dell@ubuntu:~$ g++ n.cpp -o n
n.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
n.cpp:40:62: error: invalid conversion from ‘int (*)()’ to ‘int (*)(void*)’ [-fpermissive]
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/sched.h:83:12: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘int clone(int (*)(void*), void*, int, void*, ...)’ [-fpermissive]
dell@ubuntu:~$

Comment: I believe your usage of child_stack** is causing the SEGFAULT. Although not knowing about the implementation and expectations of clone() I can not help.

Comment: I just looked up the prototype for clone(). It appears you should replace ** with * in the two places you are using it that way.

Comment: Also is 16384 bytes a large enough stack?

Comment: i tried ** by * , the result is the same , a bout the stack i think it enough, because its related with the child implementation which is just the local variables in the method cloned which is very eimple and doesnt declare any thing ! but am not sure 100% !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compiler is telling you that first argument to `clone` is supposed to be `int(*)(void*)` (a pointer to function taking one `void*` parameter and returning `int`) and that you're trying to pass it `int(*)()` (a pointer to function taking *no* parameters and returning `int`).

The former can't be implicitly converted to the latter, hence the error.

To fix it, you can define `do_something` as:

```
int do_something(void*)
{
    // your code
}
```

Comment: @jrock Thnax alot , but it gave me asegmentation fault at run time , could you see the question a gain i edited the text ., thank u

Comment: @sana That issue is worthy of a separate question - please post another one, don't edit questions like that as it makes answers obsolete. I'll rollback your latest edit.

Answer (score 1):

You really should not use the [clone(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/clone.2.html) system call. It is (sort of) reserved -like [futex(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/futex.2.html)- to the implementation of pthreads. And C++11 standard practically requires that pthreads are linked into the compiled application.

If you want to use `clone` (which is a probable mistake), retrict yourself to C, and carefully avoid the `pthread` library to be needed, even indirectly; by your application.

If you insist on using `clone`, the `child_stack` argument to it should be suitably aligned (at least to a page of 4Kbytes), and `malloc` does not guarantee that. You might use `mmap` or `posix_memalign`.

But really, don't use `clone` (specially not from C++). Use pthreads.